# Matching groups in a Python regex lookahead

Tags: python, regex

I have a ~raw download of text data from a Wordpress blog, structured as follows:

```
POST_ID_1 TITLE_1 DATE_1

This is the text from the first post ..

POST_ID_2 TITLE_2 DATE_2

This is the text from the second post ..
```

I wrote some regex to capture the `POST_ID`, `TITLE`, and `DATE`. My goal is to create a Python dictionary structured as:

```
posts = {'DATE_1': {'post_id': POST_ID_1,
                    'title': TITLE_1,
                    'text': 'This is the text from the first post ..'
                    }
        }
```

The regex to capture the headers (`POST_ID`, `TITLE`, `DATE`) is as follows:

```
header_regex_raw = r"""(\d+)\s(.*(?=January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December))(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)(\s\d+\,\s\d{4}\b)"""
```

My thought is to do something like `re.findall(header_regex_raw + (.*(?={})).format(header_regex_raw)`, but unfortunately this doesn't work as planned.

How do I capture multiple groups in a lookahead? What's a better way to create the above dict?

Comment: Can you please post some actual data in order to check your regex?

Comment: python regex has no way to capture a lookahead group with variable length. But you can capture all the header, and save the start pos in string of each header, then header end to next header pos is text.

Comment: Does this help?  https://regex101.com/r/fR9gW8/1

Comment: @SolaWing: Of course Python lookaheads can contain groups of varying length. Only lookbehind assertions need to be fixed in length.

Comment: Or with look-ahead: https://regex101.com/r/fR9gW8/3

Comment: @sobolevn, obviously, the text should be any character, not only the one in the example, this match can be broke easily by the specified text.

Comment: @sobolevn very helpful, yes! I ended up taking a different approach, which I'm sharing below.

Answer (score 1):

I found a clean function for this in the Python `re` module: `re.split`.

```
header_regex_raw = r"""(\d+)\s(.+?(?=January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December))((January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)(\s\d+\,\s\d{4}\b))"""
header_text_header = re.compile(header_regex_raw)
ret = header_text_header.split(data.strip())
```

This does exactly what I want: it captures the header elements in groups, the text that follows in another group, the following header elements in groups, etc.